# Logistic regression models in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Learning ggplot2 and don't understand why the second set of code produces an error.  All I had to do was add the aesthetics to the stat_smooth command in the third set of code and it ran fine, but I don't understand why.

```
    ggplot(df, aes(x=wave.height, y=ship.deploy)) + geom_point() + 
    stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=FALSE)


    ggplot(data = df) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = wave.height, y = ship.deploy)) +
    stat_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), se = FALSE)
    Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y


    ggplot(data = df) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = wave.height, y = ship.deploy)) +
    stat_smooth(mapping = aes(x = wave.height, y = ship.deploy),method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), se = FALSE)
```

Comment: I've voted to close the question because it has nothing to do with statistics.

Comment: In your first example, you map `x` and `y` globally in `ggplot`.  These global aesthetics pass down to the rest of the layers.  In the second example you do not use global aesthetics, instead mapping `x` and `y` only in the `geom_point` layer.  These are not passed to other layers so `stat_smooth` has no `x` and `y` aesthetics to use and you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only aesthetic mappings specified at the top level, `ggplot(aes())`, are inherited by subsequent layers. Aesthetics specified in a single layer, `geom_point(aes())` apply only to that layer.

To avoid re-specifying the same mappings, put them at the top, as in your first code.

Comment: that makes sense, understand , thank you